# How to get the model instance calling the mixin?

Tags: django

I am putting the form_valid() method into a mixin like this..

'''
class PaymentAtomicMixin(object):

```
@transaction.atomic
def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.instance = form.save(commit=False)
            ....
    ....
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
return super().form_valid(form)
```

'''

3 models are sub-classing/utilizing this mixin, and I will have to perform different actions depending on what model is executing the form_save() method. How will I know which model and the model instance is utilizing the mixin? (Django 3.2.7, Python 3.9.5)

Comment: It might be better not to use a mixin and just let the subclasses override `form_valid` instead, if those subclasses perform different actions

Comment: I made use of a common field named "prefix" in each of the models, which contains a 3-char code for a customize transaction series number. But still, it would be nice if I would know if there's a way to identify the model and the model instance calling the mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BrianD already hinted to you: this is a very bad antipattern and you probably don't want to do this. In case you're wondering how to do it in theory out of curiosity, here is an example. They key is to use `isinstance()`.

```
class MyMixin:
    prefix: str

    def show_prefix(self):
        if isinstance(self, A):
            print(f'Prefix of {self.__class__.__name__} is {self.prefix}')
        elif isinstance(self, B):
            print(f'Prefix of {self.__class__.__name__} is {self.prefix}')
        elif isinstance(self, C):
            print(f'Prefix of {self.__class__.__name__} is {self.prefix}')
        else:
            raise AssertionError(f'Class {self.__class__.__name__} is not allowed to use MyMixin')


class A(MyMixin):
    prefix = 'AAA'


class B(MyMixin):
    prefix = 'BBB'


class C(MyMixin):
    prefix = 'CCC'


A().show_prefix()
B().show_prefix()
C().show_prefix()
```

**EDIT**

After reading your answer and understanding better what you like to achieve, I would consider the following code.

```
from enum import Enum


class MyMixinPrefix(Enum):
    a = 'AAA'
    b = 'BBB'
    
    
class MyMixin:
    prefix: MyMixinPrefix

    def show_prefix(self):
        if self.prefix == MyMixinPrefix.a:
            print(f'Do A logic')
        elif self.prefix == MyMixinPrefix.b:
            print(f'Do B logic')
        else:
            raise AssertionError(f'Unknown prefix')


class A(MyMixin):
    prefix = MyMixinPrefix.a


class B(MyMixin):
    prefix = MyMixinPrefix.b


class C(MyMixin):
    prefix = MyMixinPrefix.a


A().show_prefix()
B().show_prefix()
C().show_prefix()
```

Comment: Thank you @physicalattraction.. I filtered my code like this: if self.instance.prefix == 'BP': ... elif: self.instance.prefix == 'CD':...

Comment: Indeed, if your logic is based on the prefix and not in the specific class itself, then it's also much better code. I would still consider defining the possible prefixes in the Mixin itself, and let the concrete classes select from them, so no concrete class will end up with a prefix that the Mixin doesn't know about. I added an example to the answer.